# Window coordinates changing when alertview is visible while switching rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, landscape, uiwindow

I am facing an issue with window coordinates for new `UINavigationController` as windows `rootViewController`, so I created a simple sample project which also reproduces it.

I launch the app with an initial `ViewController` having a button with the following action:

```
    - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"New VC in 3 seconds" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

    [self performSelector:@selector(delayCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

    - (void)delayCall {

    NewViewController *nvc = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nvc];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:nav];
}
```

`NewViewController` is in landscape mode, but comes up as in the below screenshot if a `UIAlertView` is shown before changing the `rootViewController` of the window and is not dismissed.

[image: New VC with wrong coordinates(should have been in landscape mode)]

If I don't show the alert view or dismiss the `AlertView` before changing the `rootViewController` the new `ViewController` comes up fine.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this? Switching `rootViewController` and showing `AlertView` is part of a larger app we are creating. Unfortunately we cannot change it now, so we'll have to find some workaround for this flow itself.

Comment: Have you tried switching your root view controller when your alert view is dismissed? This will ensure that the alert is gone when switching.

Comment: @Stonz2 yes that would solve the problem, but this switching currently happens even if alertview is not dismissed. Thanks, but need some other workaround this.